# Splitting cell with multiple data into multiple rows in more than 1 column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet with multiple data in 1 cell this happen in a couple of columns. What I need to do is split the cell into individual rows while still keep the details from the other columns

Screen 1 shows the data i got

http://imageshack.com/a/img845/1783/wxc8.png (Screen 1)

Screen 2 is what i wish the macro to output.

http://imageshack.com/a/img842/7356/7yra.png (screen 2)

The macro i found and edited in only allows me to split 1 column and i can't get the editing of the range right. the columns that needs to be split is "J" "K" "N" and "O". The columns "A"- "I" and "L""M" just needs to copy their content to the new row.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Here the Macro im using

```
Sub Splt1()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
Dim X As Variant
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
LR = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Columns("J").Insert
For i = LR To 1 Step -1
    With Range("K" & i)
        If InStr(.Value, Chr(10)) = 0 Then
            .Offset(, -1).Value = .Value
        Else
            X = Split(.Value, Chr(10))
            .Offset(1).Resize(UBound(X)).EntireRow.Insert
            .Offset(, -1).Resize(UBound(X) - LBound(X) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(X)
        End If
    End With
Next i
Columns("K").Delete
LR = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Range("L1:M" & LR)
    On Error Resume Next
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    On Error GoTo 0
    .Value = .Value
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be the `with` operator.  It constrains your selection.  Try reformulating your macro without the `with` and refer to the the ranges direct.  For example, replace your first `for` loop with something like this:

```vb
For i = LR To 1 Step -1
    If InStr(Range("K" & i).Value, Chr(10)) = 0 Then
        Range("K" & i).Offset(, -1).Value = Range("K" & i).Value
        'Range("J" ...
        'Range("N" ...
        'Range("O" ...

    Else
        K_collection = Split(Range("K" & i).Value, Chr(10))
        Range("K" & i).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(K_collection)).EntireRow.Insert
        Range("K" & i).Offset(, -1).Resize(UBound(K_collection) - LBound(K_collection) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(K_collection)

        'J_collection = Split(Range("J"...
        'N_collection = Split(Range("N"...
        'O_collection = Split(Range("O"...
    End If
Next i
```

In general I avoid `with` because it tends to obscure the visual pattern of code.

You might also consider eliminating the `.INSERT` and  `.DELETE` columns, and overwrite directly to the cells.  When working with more than one at a time, it becomes hard to keep track which column is temporary and which one is the source.  But that all depends on your preference.

Copying values for the other columns should be easy compared to this.